# Is this a valid JSON for Kendo Datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I can't get values to show in a kendo treedatasource. Is this valid JSON for the Kendo TreeDataSourc?

```
"[{\"fields\": {\"tgtWeight\": 0.0, \"hasChildnode\": true, \"parent\": null, \"currWeight\": 0.0, \"classificationNameNode\": null, \"SSM\": \"ssm4\", \"ext_model_id\": 4}, \"model\": \"equity.usersecurityselectionmodel\", \"pk\": 14}]"
```

Here is the Kendo side.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../getModelTargetWeights?id="+id,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "pk",
                parentId: "parent",
                fields: {
                           fields: { field: "fields"},
                           tgtWeight: {field: "tgtWeight", type :"number"}
                }
                }
            }
    });

   $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        editable: true,
        height: 540
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataSource schema should look like this:

```
dataSource: {
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "pk",
            parentId: "parent",
            fields: {
                parent: { nullable: true}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and each element of `JSON` array should contain `hasChildren` member

**Update:** `JSON` array itself:

```
[{\"tgtWeight\": 0.0, \"hasChildren\": true, \"parent\": null, \"currWeight\": 0.0, \"classificationNameNode\": null, \"SSM\": \"ssm4\", \"ext_model_id\": 4, \"model\": \"equity.usersecurityselectionmodel\", \"pk\": 14}]
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/uJoLo

Comment: Gene..thanks for the response.the haschildNode can be put into the hasChildren member. PareintId is parent. What I'm not sure about is the actual string. It looks like it's correct but Kendo can't parse it.

Comment: ...one comment, you took out the "fields" key to make this work. The way the data comes over is this format. I think you are asking me to change it?

Comment: @Axwack yes, kendo treelist not working with nested properties like `fields.parent`

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you kindly. That's my answer.